# Perl to Python: hash to nested dictionary and cx_Oracle

Tags: python, perl, dictionary, cx-oracle

I need to translate a perl hash to a nested, keyed Python dictionary after reading data from an Oracle database into an array.  What is the most efficient way to do this?  The existing Perl code (I don't know Perl at all) looks like this:

```
# read the data and place into a species hash (sphash) and a data hash (tmphash)
my (@lnarr, %sphash, %tmphash, $tmpln, $tmpsel, $x, $datetime) ;
while (@lnarr = $csr->fetchrow_array) {
  $datetime = $lnarr[4].'-'.$lnarr[5] ;
  $tmpln = join '_', $lnarr[8], $lnarr[9] ;
  $sphash{$lnarr[7]} = 'x';
  $tmphash{$lnarr[0].'_'.$lnarr[1].'_'.$lnarr[2].'_'.$lnarr[3].'_'.$datetime.'_'.$lnarr[6]}{$lnarr[7]} .= $tmpln ;
} #while line
```

I'm not sure what the most efficient route of creating a nested dictionary would be... any guidance would be great.

My initial code looks like this, but I'm aware that it's probably very wrong (I'm also just learning python):
The first few lines are reading a tuple from an Oracle output into a dictionary, based on this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468071/how-can-i-make-cx-oracle-bind-the-results-of-a-query-to-a-dictionary-rather-than)

```
#this is creating the dictionary from the data
cursor.execute(query, cruise6_input=cruise6_input)
desc=[d[0] for d in cursor.description]   
result=[dict(zip(desc,line)) for line in cursor]

station=[r['STATION'] for r in result]
time=[r['GMT_TIME']for r in result]
svspp=[r['SVSPP'] for r in result]
expcatchwt=[r['EXPCATCHWT'] for r in result]
beglat=[r['BEGLAT'] for r in result]
expcatchnum=[r['EXPCATCHNUM'] for r in result]
cruise=[r['CRUISE'] for r in result]
towdate=[r['BEGIN_GMT_TOWDATE'] for r in result]
stratum=[r['STRATUM'] for r in result]
beglon=[r['BEGLON'] for r in result]

tmpln=zip(expcatchwt,expcatchnum)
tmphash=zip(station,time,beglat,cruise,towdate,stratum,beglon)
keys=zip(tmphash,svspp)
```

How to I get an output of tmphash[svspp]=tmpln?  If I print tmphash[svspp] the result is simply {}....

Answer (score 2):

In python dictionary item access uses `dictionary[key]`; so you need to correct your lines for `sphash` and `tmphash`:

```
sphash[result[7]] = 'x'
tmphash[result[0] + '_' + result[1] + '_' + result[2] + '_' + result[3] + '_' + datetime + '_' +
        result[6]][result[7]] = tmpln
```

This assumes that `tmphash[somekey]` is itself already a dictionary. You could define that as a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tmphash = defaultdict(dict)
```

Now each `tmphash` key is automatically another `dict` when accessed.

Comment: How does the edited code look?  What is the benefit of using a set vs sphash?

Comment: @VictoriaPrice: Since you are only using the dict to track unique keys, a set is more efficient (no need to store all the `x` values).

Answer (score 0):

correcting your python code to the best of my abillity:

```
# I have no idear what this is suppose to do
# i guess you are trying to mimic the array assignment in
# the while loop...but I think you are doing it wrong, please update your
# poste so we can make sense of it
desc=[d[0] for d in cursor.description]
# makes a list of dicts with the entire desc array as key and one line as value?!?!
result=[dict(zip(desc,line)) for line in cursor]

tmphash = {}
spset=set() # if you want an spset instead of hash
while (True): # this should probably be a for loop with your array
    datetime="%s-%s" % results[4:6]
    tmpln='_'.join(result[8:10])
    # here you probberbly want to add to a set instead of making a hash mapping to something useless
    sphash[result[7]]='x'
    # or
    spset.add(result[7])
    # .= is a string concatination operator in perl
    # += can also concatinate strings in python
    tmphash['_'.join(result[0:4]+[datetime]+result[6:8]] += tmpln
```